# Meaning of "He rounded her up, sidling and dancing with his arms out in their big curve"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Dexter made the presentations.
>
> ‘We can’t stay, I’m afraid,’ said Elizabeth in her grand manner. The
> closed door next to the stove must lead to the bathroom: she could hear the
> dull splatter of a leaking shower tap.
>
> ‘Yes you can,’ said Dexter. He took the lid off the saucepan.
> ‘Soup!
> Soup, Billy. Soup means lots. Sit up, everyone. Where’s Arthur?’
>
> ‘At the Papantuanos’,’ said Athena.
>
> ‘I hope he’s not watching TV.’
>
> ‘They’re making suits of armour in the shed.’
>
> ‘I’ll go and get him,’ said Dexter. ‘Athena – Vicki must be sat near the
> warmth. She’s from sunnier climes, aren’t you, Vicki.’
> **He rounded her up,
> sidling and dancing with his arms out in their big curve**. Vicki scowled with
> embarrassment, but obeyed. Elizabeth abandoned her plan to watch ‘Sale of
> the Century’, and allowed herself to be shuffled to a chair. She drew off her
> gloves.

Does it mean: Vicki was seized by him while he was
sidling and dancing with his arms out toward his waist?

Does "with his arms out in their big curve" mean: with his arms out toward his waist?

Source: The children's Bach by Helen Garner

Comment: I think it's unlikely that he grabbed Vicki--"rounding up" means getting someone/something to go where you want them to, but doesn't necessarily imply physical contact. This is the kind of pose I would expect from that description: https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-farmer-rounding-up-the-sheep-15794722.html

Comment: @Katy I think you should post this as an answer. Nice link.

Comment: Many thanks, am I right in understanding the phrase: with his arms out in their big curve?

Comment: He was holding his arms out just like the man in Katy's picture; spread wide to prevent Vicki from 'escaping'. As she was one person and not a flock of sheep, he would curve his arms round her (but without touching) to encourage her to move in a certain direction.